# undefined method `instantiate' on Rails Polymorphic Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I am using rails `3.2.12`
ruby `1.9.3`
and mongoid `3.1.7` as orm/driver for mongo `2.6`

I have an address class which can be used in multiple models

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  embedded_in :addressable, polymorphic: true
end

class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  embeds_one :address, autobuild: true, as: :addressable
end

class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  embeds_one :address, autobuild: true, as: :addressable
end
```

**Not every time but on random I am getting an error on my view**

```
Started GET "/customers/asdadsdsdsdsds?sid=abcdfsd" for ------ at 2018-03-16 10:38:11 -0400
Processing by CustomersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"sid"=>"xyz", "id"=>"abc"}
  Rendered customers/show.html.haml within layouts/application (2.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 439ms
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/exception_notification-3.0.1/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_request.text.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/exception_notification-3.0.1/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_title.text.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/exception_notification-3.0.1/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_session.text.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/exception_notification-3.0.1/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_title.text.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/exception_notification-3.0.1/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_environment.text.erb (9.0ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/exception_notification-3.0.1/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_title.text.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/exception_notification-3.0.1/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_backtrace.text.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/exception_notification-3.0.1/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_title.text.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/exception_notification-3.0.1/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/exception_notification.text.erb (22.0ms)

Sent mail to me (60ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `instantiate' for Address:Class):
    40: 
    41: .dl-horizontal
    42:   %dt Address
    43:   %dd= @customer.address
    44: 
    45: .dl-horizontal

  app/views/customers/show.html.haml:43:in `_app_views_customers_show_html_haml__4324924039767281630_61736740'
```

more from backtrace

```
-------------------------------
Backtrace:
-------------------------------

  mongoid (3.1.7) lib/mongoid/factory.rb:40:in `from_db'
  mongoid (3.1.7) lib/mongoid/relations/builders/embedded/one.rb:21:in `build'
  mongoid (3.1.7) lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:43:in `create_relation'
  mongoid (3.1.7) lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:26:in `__build__'
  mongoid (3.1.7) lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in get_relation'
  mongoid (3.1.7) lib/mongoid/threaded/lifecycle.rb:125:in `_loading'
  mongoid (3.1.7) lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:115:in `block in get_relation'
  mongoid (3.1.7) lib/mongoid/threaded/lifecycle.rb:84:in `_building'
  mongoid (3.1.7) lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:114:in `get_relation'
  mongoid (3.1.7) lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:223:in `block in getter'
  app/views/customers/show.html.haml:43:in `_app_views_customers_show_html_haml___1573920893515992280_74752380'
  actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
```

**Show action**

```
  def show
    @accounts = @customer.accounts.accessible_by(current_ability)
  end
```

View is simple too just calling the address through customer

```
.dl-horizontal
  %dt Address
  %dd= @customer.address.
```

Comment: Can you add the show method in the controller and the show view?

Comment: @Pablo I have added the show method

Comment: Didn't help :) And the view? What is `customer` in the view?

Comment: @Pablo added the view, but that's simply calling address through customer

Comment: The error logs shows `customer` not `@customer`

Comment: sorry edited the question